# warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data - c++

Tags: c++, arguments, double

i ran into this problem yesterday and havent been able to fix it.
So if you could help me out Id be glad.

So I get this error:

```
warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
```

from these two lines

```
angles[0] = (float)(atanf(delta[2] / hyp) * 57.295f - MyPunch[0] * 2);
angles[1] = (float)(atanf(delta[1] / delta[0]) * 57.295f - MyPunch[1] * 2);
```

The rest of the code;

```
void calcang(float *src, float *dst, float *angles)
{
    float MyPunch[2];
    Lokalitetstjeneste.GetPunch(MyPunch);
    double delta[3] = { (src[0] - dst[0]), (src[1] - dst[1]), (src[2] - (dst[2] - 61)) };
    double hyp = sqrt(delta[0] * delta[0] + delta[1] * delta[1]);
    angles[0] = (float)(atanf(delta[2] / hyp) * 57.295f - MyPunch[0] * 2);
    angles[1] = (float)(atanf(delta[1] / delta[0]) * 57.295f - MyPunch[1] * 2);
    angles[2] = 0.0f;

    if (delta[0] >= 0.0)
    {
        angles[1] += 2.0f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `float`, use `double` for everything, including the rest of the program that calls `calcang()`.

Answer (score 3):

`delta` and `hyp` are double and the result of the division is a double , `atanf` takes a float, this is where the error comes from.

I would change `atanf` to `atan` or perform everything in double. Double has around 16 significant digits, float only around 7

Comment: Hm, thanks for the fast answer - what could I do to fix this?

Comment: depending on double is a bad idea when float is enough. There is significant performance reducing by using double always.